# How do I setup a service to keep my C# console app running in the background?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, ubuntu, console

I am trying to setup a service on Ubuntu so as to allow a simple asp.net core console app run in the background. When I run the console app from the terminal it works. That being it sends an email every 10 seconds,but when I setup the service no email is sent at all. When I check the status of the servce it shows that it is active and running.

Below is the c# code.

```
namespace EmailSender
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public static void Main()
        {
            SetTimer();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
            Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
            Console.ReadLine();
            aTimer.Stop();
            aTimer.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
        }

        private static void SetTimer()
        {
            // Create a timer with a two second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                e.SignalTime);

            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            {
                Port = 587,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("shanahdiscrete@gmail.com", "MySuperSecretPassword"),
                EnableSsl = true,
            };

            smtpClient.Send("shanahdiscrete@gmail.com", "shanahcas@gmail.com", "Annoying timed email sender", "body");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the service I have setup. Note that I commented out the direction to the same console app but that I setup as a worker service thinking that was my problem. That too gave me the same result.

```
[Unit]
Description=Timed Email Sender

[Service]
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/shanah/RiderProjects/WorkerService/WorkerService/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/WorkerService.dll
#WorkingDirectory=/home/shanah/RiderProjects/WorkerService/WorkerService/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/shanah/RiderProjects/EmailSender/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/EmailSender.dll
WorkingDirectory=/home/shanah/RiderProjects/EmailSender/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/
User=dotnetuser
Group=dotnetuser
Restart=always
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-sample-service
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Why don't use a [worker service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) here?

Comment: I tried that. The same thing happened.